# How to stop Power BI from removing duplicates when creating a data.frame using R script visual?

Tags: r, powerbi

**Problem:**
I am trying to keep all records when creating a data frame using R in Power BI.
If I enter the data into the R script visual it automatically applies unique() removing, duplicate records.  I am working with data in long format, so I do not want this to happen.

**Question:** 
How do you stop power BI from applying unique() when generating a data frame in R script visual?

**Example of code generated by Power BI**

```
      #Create dataframe
      #dataset <- data.frame(date_key)

      #Remove duplicated rows
      #dataset <- unique(dataset)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an index/unique column to the visual. In other words, create a column in the table your date_key is in and set it equal to this (and then add the column to the R visual):

```
index = 
RANKX (
    FILTER (
        yourTable,
        EARLIER ( yourTable[CC] ) = yourTable[CC]
            && EARLIER ( yourTable[Type] ) = yourTable[Type]
            && yourTable[Cluster] = yourTable[Cluster]
            && EARLIER ( yourTable[Status] ) = yourTable[Status]
    ),
    yourTable[Avg-Position],
    ,
    ASC
)
```

As seen here: https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Add-calculated-index-column-by-DAX/td-p/72448

Answer (score 4):

aGuy's answer is absolutely correct, but for those that want to add an index column that is simply a row count via the PBI Edit Queries UI, you can do it this way:

[image]

I would have added this as a comment to aGuy's answer, but I can't post images in comments.